# How to delete Telegram message from certain chat members?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I have a Telegram bot, which is group admininstator and can handle all group messages. As I understand, when group member send message, it deliver to all group members (bot receive message too).

Can I delete group message from certain chat members, after they receive message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. All Telegram operations are chat related and in case of group chat are applicable to all participants.